# SpringData JPA left join SubQuery

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

```
select sm.* 
from   system_mail sm 
left join (SELECT u.mail_code 
           from   user_mail u 
           where u.to_user = 1 ) um 
on sm.mail_id = um.mail_code 
where um.id is null.
```

this SQL was running well in mysql but wrong in SpringData JPA,how can i use it in springdata jpa?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to force using the DB Engine to run your SQL with `nativeQuery = true`:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="...yourqueryhere...")
```